# UAC setting ask Credentials for for Admin Taks but not for signing Up

Tags: windows-10, uac

I want to set UAC Setting on my Windows 10 PC such that when I log in through Admin User, It should not ask for Password but when I do Some Admin Stuff (Installing aplications, etc), It should give a prompt asking for Credentials.

Comment: The only way to accomplish that would be to run as a non-privileged user.  Any action that required elevation of permissions would then generate the UAC prompt requesting the credentials of an elevated user.  Disabling UAC entirely disables UWP applications which include the Settings application.  What problem are you trying to solve exactly?

Comment: I know but that creates many issues with some application i use